# Error de sintaxis :

Tags: python, sintaxis

Estoy intentando comprobar mi código con test y el único error que me está dando por el momento es un error de sintaxis, en los dos puntos de la primera linea, para mí incomprensible. A ver si me podéis echar una mano,muchas gracias!!```

```
class Soldier:
    def __Init__(self, name, health, strengh):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.strengh = strengh

    def attack(self):
        return self.strengh()

    def receiveDamage(self, damage):
        self.health -= damage
```

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. No es `def __Init__` es `def __init__`, la "i" primera la tienes en mayúscula. Por otro lado, **vigila la sangría**, tenias el código sin formatear adecuadamente, lo he editado, pero era imposible saber si la linea `def __init__` estaba bien sangrada o no y casi seguro que éste era el error, tal como está el código es correcto, corrigiendo lo de la "I" y asumiendo que `strengh` es un objeto llamable (otro método o función por ejemplo). Si sigues con el error el problema está en la línea anterior a `class Soldier`.

Comment: Cuando agregues código lo copias y pegas, lo seleccionas todo lo pegado y pulsas Ctrl + K o el botón {} del editor, además, con Python asegúrate de que queda identado tal como lo tienes, la sangría en Python no es decorativa, delimita los bloques de código, en tu caso después de `:` se espera un bloque con un nivel más de sangría, posiblemente no lo tenías, si es así el error debe ser: algo como `"SintaxError: expected an indented block"`

Answer (score 0):

El error es que estás poniendo `__Init__` en vez de `__init__`. Python es un lenguaje case-sensitive, lo que hace que distinga entre mayusculas y minúsculas.